Dolphin and chrome multiple tabs error, focus moves to last one on the right
After losing weeks of life I now found that the problem is the keyboard and mouse are conflicting!!!
24.04 must have something in the code that causes this, as I've used these for 3 years.
Is it that they use the same IRQ and so cause problems? As I get black screen on boot. So far I'll have to boot with no keyboard then turn on after logging in.
Very Strange behavior in Chrome and Dolphin on Ubuntu 24.04.
When I add another tab to the above the focus moves to the right and last one.
If I select the first one to open it the cursor moves to the last tab.
I cannot open another tab. I have to close the tabs until the one I want is the last one.
Please note, this does not happen in Firefox.
OK Update
I tried the trackball on a windows 10 laptop and it works as it should the focus stays on the tab I select.
So to test.

1 setup new user
2 open dolphin/ Nautilus (I Have added gnome for testing.
Open multiple tabs,
3 click the first tab and focus moves to the right, last tab

Just an update:
I added a new user and got my alt-F4 working as it should.
So    The  problem is in Gnome and plasma with dolphin/ Nautilus
Is this a new bug?
Very annoying.

Please don't add "solved" etc. to the question. If you have found an solution, post it as an answer.

Try disabling extensions one by one in Chrome (chrome://extensions/) and Dolphin to see if the issue persists.
If you’ve customized either Chrome or Dolphin, try resetting them to their default configurations to rule out any tweaks causing this behavior.
For Chrome, you can reset it in chrome://settings/ by searching for “reset settings.”

Hi Thanks for the help tried resetting Chrome and Dolphin, still the same. Such a bizare problem.

Solved for me!
It is a problem with my wireless keyboard and mouse conflicting.
Only happened when upgrading last week to clean install of 24.04.
Assume some IRQ problem maybe.
I booted without the keyboard then added it when logged in.
All fine now. This also affected VLC.
Cheers
